# Using `\displaybreak` in `\split` environment

Tags: spacing, page-breaking, align, displaybreak

I want to use `\displaybreak` in `\split` environment. I tried to use it locally and just before the `\begin{equation}...\begin{split}` block, but they both didn't work. As far as I searched, there is no way of using it properly in `\split` and `\align` environments but in `\align*` it is fine. Is that correct or is there a way to use it in these environments? If the answer is no, then I am looking for a proper way of breaking my long equations so that vertical spaces are not automatically extended.

Comment: No, you can't use `\displaybreak` in `split`.

Comment: Then how people split their long equations when they come to the end of the page without resizing or scaling anything else?

Comment: I guess that in that case (a last resource, though), you change `split` into `align` with some `\notag` for the lines where you don't want the number. But splitting a display should be an exceptional case.

Comment: you need to use a multiline display environment such as `align`, `gather`, `multline`, not a multiline block within `equation` (`split`, `aligned`)

Comment: I solved it by using `\displaybreak` locally inside `\align` as you both mentioned. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `split` environment cannot be broken across pages: for instance, when it appears in a numbered display, it gets just one equation number.

The breakable display environments are `gather`, `align`, `alignat` and `flalign`. In order to break one of these, place `\displaybreak` *before* the `\\` that ends the line.

In order to emulate breaking `split`, use `align` and `\notag` in the lines you don't want numbered.

Note that you can issue a declaration `\allowdisplaybreaks` in the document preamble which automatically breaks those environments when needed, but this should only be used when drafting the document: *you*, not a machine, should decide what's the best break point is, because it requires understanding what the formulas mean.

Comment: Can't one just wrap say align in allowdisplaybreaks, but issued as an environment. That would localize the effects and one does not need to add a lot of `\displaybreak`. It also makes it a bit more visual in the code that this align is allowed to break.